# ffmpeg - multiline text in metadata (comment tag)

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, mp3, m4a

I use ffmpeg to update metadata tags like this way:

```
ffmpeg -i "in.m4a" -acodec copy -metadata artist="artist text"
-metadata comment="comment text" "out.m4a"
```

Well, "artist text" and "comment text" is usual plain text, but comment field allows to put multiline text. Each line must have *new line character* to do it. Something like this:

```
-metadata comment="source: lastfm \r\n tags: tag1, tag2 \r\n ..."
```

But all characters that I use (\r\n, %nl%, ^N) bring no result.

I run **ffmpeg.exe** from **PHP** script on **Windows** using **shell_exec()** function

Someone help please, or tell me is it really possible?...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with PowerShell using the `` `n `` for a newline and optionally 
`` `r `` for carriage return

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.m4a -metadata comment="hello`nworld" out.m4a
```

Windows default shell is `cmd.exe` so you may need to invoke like this

```
powershell ffmpeg -i in.m4a -metadata comment="hello`nworld" out.m4a
```

Output

```
Output #0, ipod, to 'out.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    comment         : hello
                    : world
    encoder         : Lavf55.1.100
```

Comment: Yes, it is! To make it work i use full path to ffmpeg. result command right the next: **powershell D:\folder\ffmpeg.exe -i 'in.m4a' -acodec copy -metadata comment="first line`nsecond line" 'out.m4a' -y** So, Steven Penny thanks a lot!

Comment: And if path or values like `comment="my album (mix)"` contains brackets like `(`, `)`, `[`, `]` etc. then you should use single quote against double: `comment='my album (mix)'`. If it's necessary to use line breaking  symbol then the command will be: **comment='my album'"`n"' (mix)'**

Answer (score 0):

working solution for Linux:

`ffmpeg ... -metadata comment='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=text1'$'\n''https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=text2' ... output`

both **vlc** and **bash** with `ffmpeg -i output` show two lines.